# Does Elastic Beanstalk run all the deployment commands every time an EC2 instance is booted?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Python project that requires the installation and compilation of quite a few dependencies that can easily take 10-15 minutes.

If I were to use Elastic Beanstalk and auto scaling would that mean that each EC2 instance would take 10-15 minutes to boot, or does EB do more intelligent snapshotting/cloning?

Would I see much better boot up times by pre-baking AMIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea to have fast boot up times. [Elastic Beanstalk will work with custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html). Its also a good idea because if your dependencies are out of service, you won't be able to start new servers. Happened to me before :(.